# RecuRsion in R - variables not being passed?

Tags: r, recursion

I'm trying to iterate over various number to get a length of how many 'links' are in the 'chain' of computation. I take a number and do stuff if its even, do stuff if its odd and keep going till it hits 1. With my code

```
chainCount <- 0
chain <- function( n ){


  if(n %% 2 == 0 && n > 1){
    n <- n/2
    chainCount <- chainCount + 1
    print(chainCount)
    chain( n )

  }
  else if (n > 1){
    n <- 3*n + 1
    chainCount <- chainCount + 1
    print(chainCount)
    chain( n )

  }  

}

chain(13)
```

The function does 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1. For some reason the chainCount variable is not incremented on each iteration of the recursion, though, and I'm given

```
> chain(13)
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

When it should be giving me 9, since there's 9 steps in total for the process. Is there a special variable assignment in R for recursive problems like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not modify the `chaincount` variable that was set to 0 but rather creates a new `chaincount` variable inside the function:

```
chainCount <- chainCount + 1
```

Try:

```
chainCount <<- chainCount + 1
```

Comment: Or pass the counter as a variable to the function, this avoids the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should be (carefully!) using the "`<<-`" to ensure you're updating the global `chainCount`:

```
chainCount <- 0
chain <- function( n ){


  if(n %% 2 == 0 && n > 1){
    n <- n/2
    chainCount <<- chainCount + 1
    print(chainCount)
    chain( n )

  }
  else if (n > 1){
    n <- 3*n + 1
    chainCount <<- chainCount + 1
    print(chainCount)
    chain( n )

  }  

}

chain(13)

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
```

Comment: An old but useful reference on scoping: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf and a new and even more useful reference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a counter, just pass it along as an argument to the function. This avoids the global variable:

```
chain <- function( n, chainCount ){
  if(n %% 2 == 0 && n > 1){
    n <- n/2
    chainCount <- chainCount + 1
    print(chainCount)
    chain( n, chainCount )

  }
  else if (n > 1){
    n <- 3*n + 1
    chainCount <- chainCount + 1
    print(chainCount)
    chain( n, chainCount )
  }  
}

chain(13, 0)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
```